# how to set default value for Boolean in java without using constructor

Tags: java

How to set default value for Boolean in java without using constructor. I want to set Boolean value true by default and not null check. I don't want to use constructor. Is there any other annotation is present to set default value.

```
public class Address {

private String state;
private Boolean active;

public Address() {
    this.active = true;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public Boolean getActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(Boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

}
```

Comment: Just this: `private Boolean active = true;` done.

Comment: Initialize it when you declare it: `Boolean active = true`

Comment: Why don´t you want to use the constructor? That´s basically it´s job

Comment: @AlexanderHeim Unnecessary verbosity for a situation like this

Comment: For this here, maybe. But nevertheless it´s a bad programming style to set this true at the declaration if it´s not a constant variable.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim Don't think I've heard of that convention. Could you link me to your source? If the value isn't being injected or doesn't require exception handling, there's no reason to avoid initializing in the field

Comment: Why don't you use a primitive `boolean`?

Comment: If i use primitive boolean it will return the default value false ..I want to set true value for that active field.

Comment: @Vince Emigh It won´t cause problems in this case here because the program is pretty small but imagine if there wouldn´t be 2 but 20 variables. And not one person working on it but 5. Some would set the variable at declaration and some in the constructor making it extremly ugly to read and understand if they decide it would need an update. Usually we use a init method that get´s called in the constructor to save us the trouble.

Comment: You can set a primitive `boolean` to `true` in the same way you're setting a `Boolean` to `true`. @AlexanderHeim Not quite. It shows intent of the value being injected - if something isn't initialized in the field, I automatically assume there's a reason. Definitely wouldn't say it's "bad", if not preferable, depending on who you ask. Pretty opinion-based, thought it was an actual convention. But the more I think of it, the less I agree. It just doesn't make sense, IMO, especially for a larger code base. Intent plays a bigger role than "looking pretty".

Answer (score 0):

> I want to set Boolean value true by default and not null check.

You can't.  The default value for a reference type is `null`.  This stated in the Java Language Specification ([JLS 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)), and you can't change it.

If you want your initial value to be anything else, you must either use an explicit initializer in the declaration, or an assigment in the constructor.

> I don't want to use constructor.

Then use an initializer; e.g.

```
    private Boolean active = true;
```

> Is there any other annotation is present to set default value.

No<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - That is to say: there is no **standard** Java annotation.  You *might* be able to invent your own custom annotation, and implement an annotation processor or something that *rewrote* your code to add an implicit initialization.  But that's not sensible.  You are effectively changing the language ... which makes it hard for someone else to understand your code.  Also, the custom annotation processing is going to be an extra burden for the next guy to maintain.  And all to save ... typing half a dozen characters.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You could try to override the *java.lang.Boolean* class and put it in the endorsed directory... (which is deprecated)

Comment: What do you mean with override? Replacing it? You actually suggest to replace a code class like `Boolean` with an own one? And how should that help? A class doesn't define its own default value.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought he didn't want to use the constructor "new Boolean(true)"... Using no constructor at all, is not possible. I rest my case. ;-)

Comment: Well, `private Boolean active = true` would be even easier, but OP wanted to have `active` as `true` without doing anything themselves and as you say, that's not possible. Don't forget that you can also delete this answer, if you like. Or update it. :)